# Как преобразовать из множества объектов с сообщениями в один объект?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить из множества объектов, которые включает в себя поля: id, text, nickName, chatId, преобразовать в один объект, который будет включать в себя поля: messages(либо же texts, без разницы) в котором будут все сообщения из множества объектов, nickName, chatId.

Пример исходных данных:
[image: Исходные данные]

Во что нужно преобразовать:
[image: Исходные данные]

Если не грузятся картинки, то напишу текстом:

```
Мне нужно из этого: 
{ 
  id: "1", 
  text: "Проверка связи", 
  nickName: "Илья Угловской", 
  chatId: "843582698" 
},
{
  id: "2", 
  text: "Повторяю, проверка связи", 
  nickName: "Илья Угловской", 
  chatId: "843582698" 
} 
Преобразовать в это: 
{ 
  messages: {
    "Проверка связи", 
    "Повторяю, проверка связи" 
  }, 
  nickName: "Илья Угловской", 
  chatId: "843582698"
}
```

Comment: Изображения не загружаются.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, Спасибо за ваш ответ! Тогда напиши руками)

Мне нужно из этого:
{
  "id": "1",
  "text": "Проверка связи",
  "nickName": "Илья Угловской",
  "chatId": "843582698"
}
{
  id: 2,
  text: 'Повторяю, проверка связи',
  nickName: 'Илья Угловской',
  chatId: 843582698
}

Преобразовать в это:
{
 messages: {
  "Проверка связи",
  "Повторяю, проверка связи"
 },
 "nickName": "Илья Угловской",
 "chatId": "843582698"
}

Comment: Объединять нужно на основании `chatId` или `nickName`?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, желательно на chatId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
const data = [
  { "id": "1", "text": "Проверка связи", "nickName": "Илья Угловской", "chatId": "843582698" },
  { id: 2, text: 'Повторяю, проверка связи', nickName: 'Илья Угловской', chatId: 843582698 },
  { "id": "3", "text": "Baz 1", "nickName": "Foo Bar", "chatId": "1" },
  { id: 4, text: 'Baz 2', nickName: 'Foo Bar', chatId: 1 },
];

const newData = Object.values(data.reduce(
  (acc, { chatId, nickName, text }) => {
    // acc[chatId] ??= { chatId, nickName, messages: [] };
    if (!acc[chatId]) acc[chatId] = { chatId, nickName, messages: [] };
    acc[chatId].messages.push(text);
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за решение!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли здесь как-то избавится от оператора ??, в node.js мне выдает синтаксическую ошибку. А проверками на null и undefined обойтись не получается

Comment: Изменил ответ. Так подойдёт?

Comment: да спасибо большое!)